# Audio shows 'Invalid source' when linking to a file on local machine using FileOpenPicker

Tags: javascript, windows, audio, windows-runtime, mp3

I'm trying to write a JS Windows app. I have a button on the first page, and the click event handler code is as follows:

> function pickSingleAudioFile(args) {
>           document.getElementById("output").innerText += "\n" + this.id + ": ";
>
> ```
>     // Create the picker object and set options
>     var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
>     openPicker.viewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.thumbnail;
>     openPicker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.musicLibrary;
>     openPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".mp3"]);
>
>     // Open the picker for the user to pick a file
>     openPicker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (file) {
>         if (file) {
>             // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
>             WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Picked file: " + file.name, "sample", "status");
>             document.getElementById("output").innerText += "You picked " + file.name + " from " + file.path;
>
>             // Save the file as an audio tag and load it
>             var audtag = document.createElement('audio');
>             audtag.setAttribute("id", "audtag");
>             audtag.setAttribute("controls", "true");
>             audtag.setAttribute("msAudioCategory", "backgroundcapablemedia");
>             audtag.setAttribute("src", "\"" + file.path + "\"");
>             document.getElementById("output").appendChild(audtag);
>             audtag.load();
>         } else {
>             // The picker was dismissed with no selected file
>             WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Operation cancelled.", "sample", "status");
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

The path is something like "D:\Songs\song1.mp3" or "\network-share\My Music\song name.mp3" I get the "Invalid Source" error when trying to load the file.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, this:

```
audtag.setAttribute("src", "\"" + file.path + "\"");
```

should instead be this:

```
audtag.setAttribute("src", file.path);
```

It's not clear why you are adding the backslashes.  However, depending on what you are doing and based on samples I've seen, you'd be better off doing something like this:

```
var fileLocation = window.URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: true });
audtag.setAttribute("src", fileLocation);
```

You might check out the "[Playback Manager msAudioCategory Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Playback-Manager-e6526e67)" from the Windows Dev Center for more ideas.